# Scorm application performance testing using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need help and inputs for Scorm application performance testing using jmeter. How to record the scorm application using jmeter? Do I need to use any plugins for recording scorm application.

Please provide tutorials for doing the scorm application performance testing using jmeter

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to simulate real life usage of your application by creating the same network footprint in terms of [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) requests

Looking into [Wikipedia article on SCORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharable_Content_Object_Reference_Model)

> Shareable Content Object Reference Model (SCORM) is a collection of standards and specifications for **web-based** electronic educational technology (also called e-learning).

and for the [Experience API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experience_API):

> The Experience API (Tin Can API) is an open source API. It is a **Representational state transfer web service that uses JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)** for its data format.

So my expectation is that it will be sufficient to use JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers for implementing your test

You can even record the user actions using your browser (or desktop application if it's not a browser-based solution) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)